# Cannot programmatically populate an iframe with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, iframe

I want to dynamically populate an iframe with Javascript.

I do not want the iframe in a html document loaded in via src.

I do not want to use Jquery, just plain old javascript (ECMA 5.1).

Here is my code so far:

```
var elementToAttachTo = document.getElementById(attachTo);

// Need to create and attach iframe to page before populating.
// attachTo is provided as a parameter to this function, this definitely
// works as I got this working setting the iframe src to a html file..

var ifrm = document.createElement("iframe");
ifrm.setAttribute("id", "blabla");
// I set src to about:blank here, cause I read to do that somewhere...
ifrm.setAttribute("src", "about:blank");

// I attach the iframe BEFORE populating it.
elementToAttachTo.appendChild(ifrm);

ifrm = populateIframe(ifrm);
```

Here is my populateIframe function:

```
function populateIframe(iframe) {
    var ifrmHtml = iframe.contentDocument.documentElement;

    var p = document.createElement("p");
    p.innerHTML = "Hello iframe!";
    ifrmHtml.appendChild(p);

    iframe.contentDocument.documentElement = ifrmHtml;
    return iframe;
}
```

I was trying to call appendChild() directly to the iframe which didn't work, so I did some research and found examples of appending to the contentDocument.documentElement. It still doesn't work.

Many thanks for any help!

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you are using an iFrame rather than a div?

Comment: I think iframes can only be populated from the src, if you are just appending elements, then I would use a div as robin says

Comment: Yeah, the iframe must be hosted as it will process credit card data

Comment: Unless it is hosted on your server, I don't think you'll be able to tamper with it, otherwise anyone would be able to inject stuff into iframes to rob people's details

Comment: We're not worried about people tampering with the iframe, as it is hosted by us. Hence the use of an iframe. Users of the SDK will not be PCI compliant.

Comment: so your iframe does have a src? presumably the webpage responsible for taking/processing credit card data?

Comment: What happens if you try appending the iframe after populating it?

Comment: @steelstring94 I get an error trying to access the documentElement in populateIframe(), as contentDocument is null.

Comment: Solved guys. Answer incoming...

Comment: You missed to append it to the body

Comment: Hey Nikola, I did miss that, but im not sure if that was the only issue. My actual code is working with head, body and divs, I changed it to a p to simplify the question. Answer coming now. Thanks!

Comment: I reproduced your code and it works fine for me but oddly, I have to scroll down within the iframe to see "Hello iframe!"

Comment: @NikolaMitic nevermind, I tested with your change and without mine. You are correct. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @steelstring94 Thank you for testing this for me. Yes, I also got the text halfway down the scrollbar. When I use nikolas solution though, it fixes it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed to append iframe content to the body.

```
function populateIframe(iframe) {
    var ifrmHtml = iframe.contentDocument.documentElement.querySelector('body');

    console.log(ifrmHtml)

    var p = document.createElement("p");
    p.innerHTML = "Hello iframe! Ja sam faca";
    ifrmHtml.appendChild(p);

    iframe.contentDocument.documentElement = ifrmHtml;
    return iframe;
}
```

See here --> https://jsfiddle.net/nmitic/24ejkfnw/

Comment: 4 hours well spent. Thank you sir!

Comment: Yeah, I hate when that happens :D

Comment: I've been through at least 4-5 resources and examples of this issue and none of them included the body, so I never thought of it. In my original example I actually did add a body first and add divs to it, it musn't have been working for another reason. I'll just have to use TDD properly I guess and add a few lines at a time. Thanks again.

Comment: I didn't get why you code is not working, but then I inspect the dom and saw that p tag gets rendered under the body, so that's when the light turn on for me.

Comment: Annoyingly, I can't inspect the Iframe DOM, as when I try "Inspect Frame Source" it comes up as blank, I assume because it doesn't have a 'src' set. Even now with the text showing, it is blank. Very annoying for testing!